# How do I write a copy constructor for my class which has a std::stringstream member?

Tags: c++, stl

If I have a class like this, how should I write the copy constructor?

```
#include <stringstream>

class MyClass {
  std::stringstream strm;
public:
  MyClass(const MyClass& other){
    //...
  }
  std::string toString() const { return strm.str(); }
};
```

std::stringstream has no copy constructor itself, so I can't use an initialiser list like this:

```
MyClass(const MyClass& other): strm(other.strm) {}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this:

```
MyClass(const MyClass& other): strm(other.strm.str()) {}
```

Comment: In this case just the content is copied, the state of the object is not. :/

Comment: @Naszta: Yes, you imply this in your own answer. How does the code in this answer affect a `std::stringstream`?

Comment: @Naszta: You're correct. However copying a stream isn't a well defined operation, so it's left to the author to give it a context-specific definition. For example if you need to have the copied stream share the underlying buffer with the original object, you won't be able to achieve it.

Answer (score 4):

If your compiler does not support C++0x, or not want to use *move constructor*:

```
MyClass(const MyClass& other)
: strm(other.strm.str())
{
  this->strm.seekg( other.strm.tellg() );
  this->strm.seekp( other.strm.tellp() );
  this->strm.setstate( other.strm.rdstate() );
};
```

Comment: One note: in C++0x case, it is a _move constructor_!

Comment: In the first example `other.strm` is not valid argument for the move constructor.

Comment: @dalle: I used the reference from http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/io/basic_stringstream/constructor I have no C++0x capable compiler. What is the correct form?

Comment: That would be `MyClass(MyClass&& other) /*: strm(std::move(other.strm)) {}*/ = default;`. Note that a move constructor is not the same thing as a copy constructor.